# Confused about calling objects fields in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

Why do I get this error message? I'm trying to make it so that the account name of each video shows up. The users and accounts are working perfectly fine on their own. If I don't include .account_name, I just get an ugly storage code like: # 
I guess I'm confused about how to access the fields of an object within an object.

NoMethodError in Videos#index
undefined method `account_name' for nil:NilClass

```
<% @videos.each do |video|%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= video.file %></td>
        **<td><%= video.user.account_name %></td>**
        <td><%= video.name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a `Video` with no `User`.

Change this:

```
<td><%= video.user.account_name %></td>
```

to this:

```
<td><%= video.user.try(:account_name) %></td>
```

Comment: `Object#try` is a bit of anti-pattern. It's generally better to figure out why the object might be nil, and use logic to handle that case specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your relationships set up between your models.

**app/models/user.rb**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
end
```

**app/models/video.rb**:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This allows you to do things like:

```
$ rails console
> v = Video.first
> v.user.account_name
> u = User.first
> u.videos
```